# Post location to iCloud database using Swift

Tags: swift, cllocation

I am trying to post my location to an iCloud database.  I keep getting an "Expected Declaration" error that I am trying to fix but am not sure what to do.

My code is as follows:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new]

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:artwork[kArtworkAddressKey] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error){
    if (!error) {
        if (placemark.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placement = placemark[0]
            artworkRecord[kArtworkLocationKey] = placement.location
        }   
    } else {
        // insert error handling here
    }
    // Save the record to the database  
}]
```

I am a novice, so please forgive if this is a simple question.

[image]

Comment: Where is the error? If you set a breakpoint which line is causing the crash? Also, please copy and paste the error so we can see exactly what it says.

Comment: Ah, the problem here is that you are mixing Swift and Objective-C code. The file is a .swift file so needs Swift code. Everything in the top half of that file (in the screenshot) is swift. Then the code with the problem is Objective-C.

Comment: OK, you deleted the screenshot again. But that's the problem here.

Comment: I thought you could mix Objective C and Swift in Xcode 6.

Comment: You can. But not like that. When they say you can mix Objective-C and Swift they mean that in a single project you can have both Swift files and Objective-C files and they will be able to talk to each other. But each individual file can only have one language in it.

Comment: Gimme a sec, I'll translate it...

Comment: Also, your error handling is off. I imagine this is due to bad indentation. You have your error handling inside an if block where the error is nil. Actually, you have a close brace on the end of a line so it was throwing off my interpretation. (Sort you code style out to make everything easier on yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have put Objective-C into a Swift file. You can translate it like this...

Objective-C

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new]

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:artwork[kArtworkAddressKey] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error){
    if (!error) {
        if (placemark.count > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placement = placemark[0]
            artworkRecord[kArtworkLocationKey] = placement.location
        }   
    } else {
        // insert error handling here
    }
    // Save the record to the database  
}]
```

Swift...

```
let geocode = CLGeocoder()

geocoder.geocodeAddressString(artwork[kArtworkAddressKey]) {
    placemark, error in
    if error {
        // handle error
    } else {
        if let placement = placemark[0] {
            self.artworkRecord[kArtWorkLocationKey] = placement.location
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that anyway.